# App inventor blocks editor is starting slow and return error "could not download starter application..."

Tags: app-inventor

I'm trying to run blocs editor for app inventor. It's starting slowly and then returns message:

We could not download the starter application from the server in order to install it on the device. This may prevent the "Connect to Device" button from working.
This error can occur if you have tried to start the blocks editor with a previously downloaded ".jnlp" file.

I have installed last version of java, other java applications are working fine. How does make the block editor work?

Answer (score 1):

There could be lots of reasons. Which browser are you using? Did you already try another?

Probably there is some kind blocking software running on your machine, perhaps a firewall.  There have also been reports of this from misconfigured virus scanners.

You also might want to take a look at the [troubleshooting](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/troubleshooting.html) page. If this does not help, post a question in the [Getting Set Up and Connecting Your Phone to App Inventor](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/getting-started-with-app-inventor) forum.